# Replacement for E402/J402/LS3954 JFET?

Tags: transistors, jfet, replacement

I've come across old synthesizer schematics for an oscillator which makes use of a couple E402s. I am looking for a suitable replacement, and I don't think the specs have to be *spot on* at all, but I still want "professional" advice.
The source gets between 5 and 10 volts, the drain delivers that voltage minus whatever drop across the JFET, and the gate gets 5 volts so the circuit isn't very demanding. If you need more info I'll gladly add it since I have no clue what info you need to find a replacement.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

The 'E402' is an N-channel JFET pair in a single package. 2N3954 was its replacment, but not easy to find.

More here: http://analogue-heaven.1065350.n5.nabble.com/Moog-2N3958-replacing-E402-td29183.html

A few candidates:

NTE [NTE461](https://www.nteinc.com/specs/400to499/pdf/nte461.pdf)

From Linear Systems, [LS3954](http://www.linearsystems.com/lsdata/datasheets/Copy_201130%20-%20LS3954A%20LS3954%20LS3955%20LS3956%20LS3958%20Rev%20A13%20dated%202019%2007%2025%20-%20Peter.pdf)

On Mouser, [2N3954](https://www.mouser.com/Search/Refine?Keyword=2N3954):  It's $23. Ouch.

Comment: Yeah, I just want super cheap but still functional JFETS since I'm selling these and trying to keep manufacturing costs low (and I don't want to deplete the worlds supply of these things lol) so I will research if these JFETS need to be electrically matched. I think they do.